# 'Yes/No Attribute' in magento - how to get text value

Tags: magento-1.8, product, product-attribute

```
$attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $code);
         $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
       foreach($options as $option){
          echo '<p class="question"></p>';
          echo '<input type="radio" id="'.$code.$option["value"].'" value="' . $option["value"] .'"  class="styled" name=" '.  $code . ' " />';
          echo '<label for="'.$code.$option["value"].'">';
          echo $option["label"];
          echo '</label>';
         }
```

Is there a way to get question front end label ? $option[value] is 1/0 and $option[label] is Yes/No - i need to get the "question text"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are using wrong method `isAttributeText`

If you want to access the value of Product Attribute then

```
 $_product->getData('attribute_code');
```

End If you want tot Display Label Of that Attribute then

```
 $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code')
```

OR

```
 $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

And then you can check using `isset()` of PHP.

Hope you got Proper Answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want values for quoted items then you have to use

```
 $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
      ->getQuote()
      ->getAllItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $disableDiscounts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getDisableDiscounts();
    echo $disableDiscounts;
}
```

Where attribute code is `disable_discount`.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution is

```
if($_product->getData('attribute_code')) {
    echo 'enable';
} else {
    echo 'disable';
}
```